# Optimization taking into account the shape of the optimization surface

Tags: r, optimization

I want to find the maximum of my multidimensional optimization surface, but I want to find not just the local maximum (highest), but the maximum that seems to me the most stable from my point of view. He should be not only tall but also wide

I will explain in the picture with one-dimensional space
[image]
The picture shows two maximums, red is the global maximum but I would not like to take it, it looks more like an outlier. I would like to take the green maximum as it is more suitable for me

My question is: how can this be done in R or is there a ready-made package that does this
**UPD=======**

This should be the maximum point around which also gives good results in terms of the fitness function.

1. the wider the area from these points, the better
2. the higher the values of the fitness function in this area, the better

**UPD=======**

fitness function probably stochastic

**UPD2========**

I am trying to find neural network weights for very unstable data with my fitness function..
Data transformations, cross validation doesn't work for me.
I assume that the model will work if I find a fairly stable maximum when optimizing the weights.
I assume that if the maximum is wide, then the model will work better with unstable data.
The picture is just an example (I have no idea what the optimization surface looks like)
[image]
[image]

The bottom line is that I do not need global maximums, I need a wide maximum for the stable operation of the neural network

Comment: `the most stable from my point of view` what is your point of view? Can you define it exactly?

Comment: Is the objective function stochastic (random)?

Comment: i made an update

Comment: please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than coming up with your own abstraction.  Then the experts can help you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: see my update please

Comment: Your update just added another abstract example but in 2D instead of 1D. What is *your* case? In your question update, you show a surface (and the question is just about finding a maximum on this surface), but in the comments on my answer, you said that you do not know this surface.

Comment: Also, it is interesting to know what the reason is for these peaks or what the properties are. Based on knowledge of those peaks you can make better algorithms that ignore them.

Comment: Sorry, but I wrote http://prntscr.com/sA8XcTTpuu2m Honestly, I don’t know how else to clarify my question

Comment: mrt.T do you at least have ideas how I can improve my answer? I have no ideas how to improve it without more information.

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of how to do "SANN smoothing" anyway I accept your answer and will try your ideas from the comments. thanks a lot

Comment: To be honest, I just learned about this property of SANN today, and so I will add some more information about it later if I find some time (since I have the interest to learn about it myself)...

Comment: ... note that your question is not very bad but just a bit vague and broad. If you could specify/clarify the problem more then it could be an interesting case relating to the broader issue of finding an optimum when the cost function is noisy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would not like to take it, it looks more like an outlier

Several algorithms for outlier detection and removal could work.

In the image it seems that if you use a simple smoothening of the curve then the weight of small peaks becomes less and this would already do the job.

How to smoothen or detect outliers for best performance in you application, for instance how to determine by which degree you smoothen, depends on what you exactly want to achieve and what this maximum is supposed to do.

What do the peaks/outliers mean, how do they arrise, and why do you not wish to take them into account?

Possibly using some more advanced filter might be better than just a simple moving average. The green curve that you got there in the picture also seems to do the job already.

---

From the comments it seems like this problem is about a situation where the points on the surface are not already sampled for the entire space (like in a grid search or parameter sweep). So this relates to some optimization problem that follows a path.

But in this case you can *still* make use of outlier detection and smoothening.

Namely, you can incorporate the expressions that do the smoothening inside your cost function. For instance, instead of sampling the cost function in a single point you could also sample points in the neighbourhood and take an average.

In this case you probably want to use some smoothening that doesn't use too much data points and uses local information. I imagine you could use some average or possibly a small [kernel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) to blur the values.

Several optimisers are already doing this sampling in multiple points, in order to find the derivative of the surface (the method SANN* in the package `optim` searches for an optimum by sampling several points and applying a Gauss-Markov kernel filter). Possibly you could tune them to obtain a bit more extra points and smoothen more strongly at the same time. You can do this also yourself by providing functions for the value and derivative of the cost function that apply the smoothening and use those with an optimiser.

Some packages seem to exist that are dealing with this problem. For instance `tgp` has [some version of `optim`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/tgp/html/optim.tgp.html) that works with noisy functions.

---

*Bélisle, Claude JP. ["Convergence theorems for a class of simulated annealing algorithms on ℝ d."](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3214721) Journal of Applied Probability 29.4 (1992): 885-895.

Comment: This is an optimization surface, it is not ready-made to take and smooth

Comment: @mr.T you don't explain in the question why it can not be smoothened or otherwise filtered. From the image that you showed I see that you have a curve (set of points) that can be easily smoothened by several different algorithms and in addition you already have this green curve which seems to be already doing what you ask for.

Comment: The picture was for an example of what kind of maximum I need, and which one is not needed ..
If we are talking about optimization, it is obvious that the optimization surface is not known, this is the essence of optimization - the search for unknown parameters, obviously on the unknown optimization surface

Comment: @mr.T can you explain that in the question. It is not obvious that the optimization surface is unknown (e.g. if you do a grid based search for an optimum then you have a bunch of points in that surface based on which you could draw an image of the surface).

Comment: The smoothening can still be done when you do not know the entire surface. For instance, you can adapt your cost function to be the average on several points in the neighbourhood of the estimate rather than the value in a single point. For several types of smoothening you can incorporate it into the formula of the cost function.

Comment: So that is what I meant with *"How to smoothen or detect outliers ... depends on what you exactly want to achieve and what this maximum is supposed to do."*. If you specify the problem more clearly then a more detailed answer can be given about the sort of smoothening or outlier detection that would be most suitable.

Comment: Interesting, thanks I'll think about it more deeply